# Arrow keys in GDB (window mode) not working with TERM=xterm

Tags: xterm, gdb

First, this is not the history size problem.

```
(gdb) show history size
The size of the command history is 70000000.
```

Second, it happens in xterm and not in vt100 and I don't want vt100 because of weird color schemes and stuff.

Is there any way to tweak xterm to allow arrow keys as to go through the list of previous commands?

Answer (score 0):

With `TERM=xterm`, the cursor-keys are defined for *application mode*, which doesn't work for applications which don't initialize the terminal.  You could set [`TERM=xterm-noapp`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-noapp) (if you have the full terminfo database), which doesn't use application mode.

Further reading:

- [My cursor keys do not work](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode) (ncurses FAQ)
- [Why can't I use the cursor keys in (whatever) shell?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows)